# Android - TouchDrag moves image within view, but need entire view to move

Tags: java, android

My image simply moves within my image view based upon the touch location.  I need the entire view to move (not just the image in it).

Here is my code in onTouch:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)v;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(),event.getY());
        mode = DRAG;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = NONE;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mode == DRAG)
        {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
        }
        break;
    }
    image.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's only the image that moves because you're doing it by calling `setImageMatrix` on the `ImageView`. If you want the entire view to move, you can try using a manipulating a `canvas` with the view that you want.

Check out a helpful resource here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: Thanks for this.  I've been through 10 multi touch tutorials now and they all do things so different from one another and are a lot more complicated than the simple way defined in that link.